# Saving pdf File in Android

Tags: android, pdf

im building an android App that download books in pdf format from url and storage it into the device , so i wrote this code to make folder named " Mypdf " and save the file after it download in it , but when i run the app in the device i only found Mypdf file but there is no any pdf book , below the code i used

```
  class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

        try {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Mypdf");
            file.mkdir();

        URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Mypdf/ "+booknameText+ ".pdf");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;

        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
             Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
             mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Book You downloaded had been saved into your SD Card " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

}

i used this function :

```
   OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/ "+booknameText+ ".pdf");
```

but some times many device's do'not have sdcard so the file will not be saved , so please can you help guys

Comment: You need to check the Exception in `catch (Exception e)`, to see if something's failing. At least, `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: when i used to use FileOutputStream("/sdcard/ "+booknameText+ ".pdf"); it worked fine in device which have sdcard

Comment: It's probably this line: `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Mypdf/ "+booknameText+ ".pdf");`. You should be giving an absolute path to the file, which you can easily do using the `File` object you created for the directory: `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(file, booknameText + ".pdf"));`. You should still be doing something with the Exception in the `catch` block, though. Otherwise you end up in situations where you don't know what the problem is; like this situation, for instance.

Comment: Thanks it work fine  :D  @MikeM.

Comment: But how i can make the new pdf file get it name , i tried using  
                                                                                                                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(file,    / "+                            booknameText +".pdf"));        but im getting an error can you help @MikeM.